# $_SESSION['mydata'] disappears in MW

Tags: mediawiki

I am trying to understand how MW 1.31.1 works. I have the following hook:

```
$wgHooks['UserLoginComplete'][] = 'onUserLoginComplete';

function onUserLoginComplete(User &$user, &$inject_html, $direct){
      $_SESSION['mydata']  = 'some data';
}
```

It basically stores some data in $_SESSION when a user is successfully authenticated. How can I keep $_SESSION['mydata'] in session as long as I am authenticated.

The puzzling thing to me is when I checked "Keep me logged in" at signin and come back to the wiki site a few hours later. I am still authenticated with the system, but $_SESSION['mydata'] disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 1.27 when [SessionManager](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:SessionManager_and_AuthManager) was introduced, MediaWiki does its own session handling. Depending on the value of [`$wgPHPSessionHandling`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgPHPSessionHandling) it will either ignore PHP sessions completely or try to sync them with MediaWiki sessions. Use MediaWiki's session handling methods instead:

```
SessionManager::getGlobalSession()->set( 'mydata', 'some data' );
```

As for data disappearing from the session, it is not meant as a persistent storage mechanism and the long-term behavior is entirely dependent on what storage mechanism is configured for it - check [`$wgSessionCacheType`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgSessionCacheType) and [`$wgObjectCacheSessionExpiry`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgObjectCacheSessionExpiry).

Comment: Tgr, thanks for the info. I tried to make "sync them with MediaWiki sessions", but no success. Would you mind posting the settings to make it work on Windows machine? Again, thanks!

Comment: The default settings should keep backwards compatibility with $_SESSION. Your problem is more likely session expiry - as I said "Keep me logged in" does not make the sessions longer, it just detaches the login status from the session. You probably want longer sessions; see the links at the end of my answer. With the default configuration you probably just need to increase $wgObjectCacheSessionExpiry.